# How to write shell script to enter commands into a console program

Tags: shell, command-line

I have to open up a command-line program and type in the following commands

```
 # From the command-line
 $ ./console.sh

 Welcome to Super Awesome Program 1.0 that I didn't write!
 Type 'help' to see all the commands supported.

 > some_command1 arg1
 Done.
 > some_command2 arg2
 Done.
 > some_command3 arg3
 Done.

 ...

 > some_command100 arg100
 Done.
```

Obviously I don't want to write a hundred of these commands.  Is there an automated way to do this?

I tried

```
echo "some_command3 arg3" | ./console.sh
```

But that didn't work.

In general, is there a nice way to do this?

EDIT: A lot of the comments asked me to look at "console.sh".  I looked at it and it seems like "console.sh" is just a wrapper for Java binaries.  Here is the gist of "console.sh": https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c1d9b05b94f3960f058

Comment: Since "console.sh" is apparently a shell script, your easiest option is to open it and look at it's innards. Then customize to your liking.

Comment: As we don't have `console.sh`, it's pretty hard to determine whether it will accept input like you're wanting. But you have the source to `console.sh`, so you can look to see how it works and whether it will do what you'd like it to do.

Comment: it would be much easier to write a simple c/c++ command line program, you don't need to know a lot to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use `xargs`

for your specific case - it's:

```
    echo "some_command3 arg3" | xargs -I {} ./console.sh {}
```

you can read more about xargs here http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/Example-Uses-Of-The-xargs-Command.htm
and in `man xargs`

if you want to execute hundreds of commands+arguments - you better first store them in some
file and then use it as input to xargs.